# Discord bot mention py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I would like to make a discord bot that when I mention someone in the server, the bot would make something with that exact person that I mentioned. For example:

Me: hug @friend

bot: @author has hugged @friend

if its possible I would also like to know if I can make the bot to send a gif

Comment: Yes, you can. Good luck with that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) message attribute to find all users mentioned in a message. Send a gif just with the gif's url.

Comment: Oh, thanks, but I think I still need a little more help.                                                                    if message.mentions:
      mention = message.mention
      await message.channel.send('Hi' + mention)                                                                    Im trying to do something simple like this but I dont know why it doesnt work.

Comment: You need two equal signs

Comment: What do you mean?